# Intercepting calls to Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, security, google-analytics

I'm want to intercept calls to Google Analytics, but don't have any clue about how to start or where to research.

I know that webmasters include the Google Analytics script to their pages, however my JavaScript knowledge is non-existent. Is the script always part of the HTML file of the website you're visiting, or can it be stored as a separate JavaScript file?

How could I make my browser use my own script instead of the Google one, so that I could log calls or open a pop-up telling me the site I'm visiting is trying to use the Google Analytics script?

I'm not asking for a detailed walkthrough (although I definitely wouldn't mind :D). Since this is really new stuff for me, any help would be appreciated, be it a link which might help me figure it on my own, or some suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has developed a debugging version of the GA JavaScript that does logging and might be of some use. If you're using Google Chrome then you can use their extension to load it into sites that you don't own and check out what's being sent to Google. See the following link for the extension:

https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna

Answer (score 1):

> How could I make my browser use my own script instead of the Google one, so that I could log calls or open a pop-up telling me the site I'm visiting is trying to use the Google Analytics script?

Use a web proxy or modify your hosts file to force your browser to send HTTP requests for google-analytics.com to a local webserver.  That local webserver can serve your code instead of the Google code.

Answer (score 0):

> I know that webmasters include the
>   Google Analytics script to their
>   pages, however my JavaScript knowledge
>   is non-existent. Is the script always
>   part of the HTML file of the website
>   you're visiting, or can it be stored
>   as a separate JavaScript file?

Can, like all javascript, be stored in a separate file.

> How could I make my browser use my own
>   script instead of the Google one, so
>   that I could log calls or open a
>   pop-up telling me the site I'm
>   visiting is trying to use the Google
>   Analytics script?

You can easily detect if the analytics script is installed (by checking for some variables, `_gaq` if I remember correctly). Intercepting it would require a bit more effort though, like monitoring the network for traffic to Google Analytics' servers or hacking into the javascript.